# ReportViewer pdf export with embeded font

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, pdf, reportviewer

Is there any way to include an embedded font with a pdf export from the .NET report viewer control?

Answer (score 3):

PDF export from report viewer prior vs 2010 (v9 and previous) did not embed fonts properly in pdf. Since [version 10](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a941c6b2-64dd-4d03-9ca7-4017a0d164fd&displaylang=en) it's working as it should - subsets of all used fonts are embedded in exported pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do this, you could render the text as an image using GDI+ in .NET and then embed that image?

Would that be a possibility for you?

Thanks,

Phil.